# Search and Edit Text Files w/ Batch

Tags: batch-file, search, edit

I'm fairly new with batch scripting, and currently trying to make my work easier (which will please my boss) with a script. Is there a way for a batch file to search a specific given input inside a text file, and `echo` into the text file?

For example, the text file looks like this:

```
4/11/2016
01530594
Time In: 1:30
01565832
Time In: 2:32
```

The given string is, in this example, `01530594` and I need to search for it inside the text file, and record the time out to make it look like this:

```
4/11/2016
01530594
Time In: 1:30
Time Out: 3:21
01565832
Time In:
```

If other stuff is needed to make it easier (say, already have `Time Out:` from the beginning, without a time) is required, that's more than acceptable.

I know search/replace/edit stuff with a batch file is tedious, is this possible?

Comment: sorry, you can't edit a file with batch. You will have to read it line by line (`for /`?) and write to a new file (you can delete the original and rename the copy afterwards)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set "timevalue=3:21"
(
  for /f "delims=" %%i in (infile.txt) do (
    echo %%i
    echo %%i|find "Time In:" >nul && echo Time Out: %timevalue%
  )
)>outfile.txt
```

The `for` loop reads the file line by line. The first `echo` writes the line to the outfile.

The second `echo` line is a bit more complicated:

`echo %%i|find "Time In:"` looks, if the line contains the string "Time In:". `>nul` writes its output to nirvana (we don't need it, we only want to know if it is there).

`&&` means "execute the next command, if the previous command was successful (that was `find`). If so, write an additional line `Time Out: %timevalue%`

Put the whole `for` loop into a block (between `(` and `)` and redirect it's output to a file

Comment: Hey Stephan, thanks for helping me out through this. I sort of implemented what you gave here to make it work with my stuff, and it sorta works, but I only have a few questions; how do I delete the previous file and rename the copy file? I believe this is messing up the loop. In case it helps, this is the code I have so far:

Comment: edit: nevermind, it's messy due to end of lines, but I think you get the idea.

Comment: `del infile.txt` and `ren outfile.txt infile.txt`

Comment: Works, thanks. But one more thing (I'm sorry lol): I edited the code you provided so that it searches for a specific string, and it works. Now I need it to read the next line, and if it contains "Time Out:" then do nothing, otherwise, write the "Time Out:" stuff. I could create another question for this with the code if necessary.

Comment: @ricknaght I'd recommend searching around a bit for your answer for that--I think you'll find what you need.  If not, ask that as a separate question.